# How to regex for multiple dots end with char or digital?

Tags: regex, node.js

I am using Node.js.   I am facing problem of the below strings

```
 2.  Dating Basics. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .i
 5.  Breaking Up . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 47
```

Here i want remove continues dots(including space) with end with char or digits.

I am using the following regex

```
 ((\.(\s)?\.)+)(\s+)?(\w+)
```

But i am not getting entire dots.   How to remove continues dots?

I need the following output:

```
 2.  Dating Basics
 5.  Breaking Up
```

Any one assist me.

Comment: The first parenthesis contains *two* unconditional dots.  You are only matching pairs of dots with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
[\s.]+\w+$
```

[See it at here regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yC9fT9/2).

Answer (score 0):

Mayby like this:

```
^[\w \w]+
```

Just look for 2 words...

Comment: No  i want remove multiple dots and following word or digits.

Comment: Maan, I think u need to be more specific. You gave input and desired output. So what else?

Comment: Actually, first two words are not fixed.  It may more word.   So i want remove multiple dots with space.

Answer (score 0):

Following matches n number of dots starts with a dot space followed by a set of character or number combinations.

```
\. \...*[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

You can do something like this to remove the matching (regex replace)

```
s/\. \...*[a-zA-Z0-9]//g
```

Comment: No.  It catches two lines. (entire para)

Comment: I have updated the regex. Tested with sed.


``cat file | sed -e 's/\. \...*[a-zA-Z0-9]//g'``

 ``2.  Dating Basics``
 ``5.  Breaking Up``

Comment: @terminalninja why are you using [a-zA-Z0-9] if you are using .*

Comment: @SheikhJames because it should not match with any special characters. the question specifically says its should be a char or a dig at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?<words>[^\.]\.\s[^\.]+)(?<dots>(?:\.\s)+\.)(?:\s?\w+)
```